# three months workout building visible body

Tags: muscle-gain

I workout more than 6 months. I eat fruits, protein, vegetables and much more meals than my will to eat. The truth is 64 kg before and now I am  67 kg.

My body has shown results with little visible muscle. I have heard on three months someone building body with visible muscles. I don't.

I have a nice program for full part of body, I sleep enough more than 8 hours a day, I drink a lot water at least 1 litre a day. I stop joking (only one time a week for 3 hours). Is true that muscles can be much visible of a thin guy or we are talking for peels (unhealthy way with "drugs") in three months?

I look my food I don't buy protein from shops. I take Quaker, eggs, chicken etc for protein not chemicals. Someone can build visible muscles in three months or I don't doing something right? Six months and not terrible results to be so obvious my muscles but yes I have progress.

Comment: People (even skinny people) can build visible muscle in three months. The problem is what people *THINK* they should look like after three months. The better gauge to see if you're building muscle is if you're progressing to heavier weight. Over 2 years I've gone from doing calf raises with 320lbs to 515lbs and seen very little muscle growth compared to strength gain. 

Everyone develops differently and everyone's "day one" starts in a different place. 6 lbs of lean muscle gain is awesome; but, probably spread over your entire body.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to record your body measurements. Many times I have been surprised (both good and bad) at the real indicators of growth or decline when I take a measuring tape to each body part.

Also gauge by how your actual progress is going. Are to steadily moving up in either weight lifted or reps performed? If not you may be in a rut and need to switch up your workouts. They should never be easy as gains are made from pushing your body to work harder than it has before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if you're making progress, try to measure more than just your bodyweight. Measure your fat percentage, and maybe the size of things like your chest, arms and legs. If they are getting bigger and muscles are getting more visible, you're definitely making progress.

The thing is, **everyone has different genetics**, and that determines whether you're gonna grow fast or not, so you can't really compare yourself with others in regards to your progress.

If you see **results**, get **heavier**, and notice that your **strength is going up**, I don't think you should worry to much about what you look like in comparison to others.